# Keyboard not working properly in terminal

Tags: keyboard, command-line, 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2, and my keyboard doesn't work normally in terminal. When I press the arrow keys, the characters "a", "b", "c", or "d" appear. The <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is also not working.

Comment: I know! But there are some commands in terminal. By that keyboard starts working neatly. So I'm looking for them.

Comment: The ALT key on your keyboard is stuck, most likely.

Comment: @gertvdijk That'd explain the ABCD bit, but not backspace failing (alt+backspace deletes previous word, doesn't disable it)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444270/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ubuntu will install vim-tiny, a bare-bones version of vim. When you type vi in the terminal, it will start this minimal vim in vi compatible mode by default. From a normal vim user's standpoint, this is horrible, since vi compatible means backspace and all the normal vim behavior will behave in the original vi manner.
so, install vim by typing the command :

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

problem solved !! enjoy programming  ;) :)